# node + phantomJS pdf rendering WITH query string?

Tags: node.js, pdf-generation, phantomjs

I'm trying to generate a PDF using PhantomJS from node. Works just fine.... until I pass in a query string. For example, this works:

```
page.open("http://localhost:3002/print/render/dispatch/client",   
function (status) {
   if(status == "success"){
      window.setTimeout(function () {
        page.render(system.args[2]);
        console.log("ok");
        phantom.exit();
      }, 1000);

  } else {
    console.log("failed - " + status);
    phantom.exit();
  }
});
```

But this does not:

```
page.open("http://localhost:3002/print/render/dispatch/client?date=2-1-15",   
function (status) {
   if(status == "success"){
      window.setTimeout(function () {
        page.render(system.args[2]);
        console.log("ok");
        phantom.exit();
      }, 1000);

  } else {
    console.log("failed - " + status);
    phantom.exit();
  }
});
```

Thoughts? thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean with "this does not"? Please edit your question to include the behavior that you see. What do you see on the console? What files are created? Please register to the [`onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html), [`onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html), [`onResourceError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html), [`onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: I do get an onconsolemessage CONSOLE: Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release.  CONSOLE: 2-1-15 (from line #undefined in "undefined") CONSOLE: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'data.data.dumpsters') at http://localhost:3002/dispatch/js/dispatch_app_track.js:108

Comment: the problem is that I'm getting blank white PDFs. nothing rendered to them.

Comment: Please add all of the information into the question itself and delete your comments afterwards.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't provide enough information to help you. You will need to find yourself, why `data.data` is undefined or post the relevant code here.